# Dataset Not Showing In Einstein Analytics

Tags: rest-api, einstein-analytics

I have executed a CSV file upload through the REST API using the `InsightsExternalData` and `InsightsExternalDataPart` objects.

When I log into the Einstein Analytics platform and look in the Data Manager, it shows that the files were uploaded successfully.  However, when I go into the `Data` tab and look at the `Datasets`, none of these show up.  See screenshot below

These datasets sometimes show up on the main wave page, but when I click on them, I receive an error stating that I do not have access to this dataset or it has been removed.

This is a developer company, so I am the only account set up in the org and should have full administrative rights.

[image: Data Manager Jobs]